# Equivalent of WM_SETTEXT when there are no handles

Tags: c#, c++, user-interface, winapi

## Goal

Writing code (C#/C++) to change text on a running Windows EXE application.

## Issue

The application does not have any Handles for its internal controls.

## What I tried

- Using *Spy++* and similar apps to get more details about the targeted application, but I got no handles for the controls. So, I suspect that it's probably WPF or something similar, and **not** WinForms or MFC.
- Using *Snoop* WPF - although I did got access to the relevant *TextBlock* control that is in question - I was not able to change the text.
- Using various *UiAutomation* (2/3) based software - all gave me the same result: I **can** access the *TextBlock* in question, but cannot set its value. Seems like only non-readonly controls are supporting such actions.
- I thought that's it's an embedded browser within the main app, but after using the *inspect.exe* tool I'm mostly convinced that this is not the case.

## My question

Is there a way to set value of a running application - just like good old WM_SETTEXT, but for cases without Handles?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need a handle to identify the control. There's no generic *send some control a message* functionality. How would that work? You wouldn't expect to send a letter that had no address information and expect it to get to your intended recipient. The postal system doesn't work like that, and neither does Windows.

Comment: @Ken UIAutomation exists to allow access to UI in a standardised way. It does not require controls to be windowed.

Comment: If a widget is read-only, the application assumes that it cannot be changed outside its control. UI Automation doesn't attempt to break an application's invariants. And even if the application in question were to offer a custom automation protocol, it certainly wouldn't allow you to violate its assumptions either.

Comment: @KenWhite I know that we need a handle for WinForms but *Snoop* is able to modify text in WPF applications even when there's no Handle. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: Snoop is [open source](https://github.com/snoopwpf/snoopwpf).

Answer (score 3):

If the program does not use windowed controls and does not support setting the text through UIA then there is no standardized means of setting the contents. The program may have an API of its own although this is unlikely.